# как на этапе компиляции проверить, можно ли к объекту применить индексацию квадратными скобками[ ]?

Tags: c++

как на этапе компиляции проверить, можно ли к объекту применить индексацию квадратными скобками[ ]?

Comment: Вам показывали концепты.

Comment: Прочитал про них, класная штука

Comment: Так напишите любое выражение с квадратными скобками. Если к объекту нельзя применить такую индексацию - то будет ошибка компиляции.

Comment: ` list<int> k;
    if constexpr (requires{k[0]; })
        cout << "very ggod!" << endl;
    else
        cout << "bad!" << endl;`

Comment: наподобие этого, если объект перегружает квадратные скобки, то выполнять первую часть, иначе вторую но без ошибки компиляции